# Winform label text not showing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following code:

```
Hide()
if(a > b)
{
label.Text = "a is greater than b";
Show();
Thread.Sleep(50000);
}
```

What i am trying to do is hide the winform as soon as app starts. If a>b at any point it will show the winform with that message in the label for 50 second and will hide again. 
Also label is set to autosize = true;

Above code works but label is not showing any text? Also is this the right approch to show the winfor for sometime using thread sleep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as above says, it is because the sleep, the UI does not have time to update it yet.

however, you do not have to use timer. DoEvents() gives it some time to update UI.

try

```
   Hide();
if(a > b)
{
    label.Text = "a is greater than b";
    Show();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(50000);
}
```

Comment: Do not use DoEvents... As stated often enough, the use of DoEvents is not recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Thorsten is right, Sleep is freezing the UI thread, so the UI is not refreshed, but you could also do something like this as a workaround:

```
Hide()
if(a > b)
{
    label.Text = "a is greater than b";
    Show();
    Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

But the cleanest solution of course is:

```
Hide()
if(a > b)
{
    label.Text = "a is greater than b";
    Show();
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(5000))
        .ContinueWith(() => Close(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

But don't forget to add the proper using clause to use the Task Parallel Library:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

The TPL is available in .NET 4 onwards. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: What is Task in this case? C# is not recognizing Task and TaskScheduler? Am i missing some using statements?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `Thread.Sleep` causes the application to pause the current thread - this means that during these 50 seconds no updates occur on the form.

What you need to do to achieve what you want is to start a timer that elapses after 50 seconds and in the timer's code, hide the form.

The timer can be  a Windows Forms timer component placed on the form.

Comment: Actually this code is inside of a timer event already. So is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid pausing threads in UI classes. The last thing you want is an unresponsive interface!